# PostgreSQL revoke privileges from column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-grant, postgresql-9.5

I have a user group named `editor_users` in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database. And my  **product** table is granted `select, insert, update and delete` to `editor_user` members.

But I want to prevent my id column. Nobody may not update id column. How can I revoke update privileges from users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could give privileges for every column. Assuming you have a table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id serial primary key,
    mytext text
);
```

You can grant privileges to `editor_user` like that:

```
GRANT SELECT(id), INSERT(id) ON product TO editor_user;
GRANT SELECT(mytext), UPDATE(mytext), INSERT(mytext), REFERENCES(mytext) ON product TO editor_user;
```

Comment: I have 15 columns. Does REVEOKE comment do this only one command? I do not want to write column names for all tables.

Comment: I guess no. `REVOKE UPDATE(id) ON product FROM GROUP editor_user;` will have no effect, if you granted all on the complete table.

Comment: You could write a script with `SELECT * FROM information_schema.column_privileges WHERE table_name = 'product'` and change privileges for all columns except `id`

Comment: excerpt from [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-grant.html] (postgresql) "Granting the privilege at the table level and then revoking it for one column will not do what you might wish: the table-level grant is unaffected by a column-level operation."

Answer (score 3):

You have two options here.  The first is to revoke to the table and grant to the columns.  If you do this, then it is worth using the `Indoemation schema` or system catalogs to discover all the relevant columns and programmatically creating the grant statements.  If you go that route `array_agg` and `array_to_string` are your friends.

for example you could:

```
revoke all on table product from public, ...;
select 'grant insert(' || array_to_string(array_agg(attname), ', ') || ') to ... ;' 
  from pg_attribute
 where attrelid = 'product'::regclass and attnum > 0;
```

Then copy and paste the output into the psql window.